# Standalone hazelcast expired event not working, but embedded hazelcast expired event does work

Tags: spring-boot, cluster-computing, hazelcast, event-listener, ttl

I used embedded hazelcast on `localhost:5701`.

Later I changed config. Now I use standalone hazelcast instances on `app-server:5701`, 3 machines built into 1 cluster. Everything works fine, except expired event.

Cache configuration is rather simple and common:

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class ExpiredListener implements EntryEvictedListener<String, Application>, EntryExpiredListener<String, Application> {
    private final ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

    @Override
    public void entryEvicted(EntryEvent<String, Application> event) {
        publisher.publishEvent(new ApplicationCacheExpireEvent(this, event.getOldValue()));
    }

    @Override
    public void entryExpired(EntryEvent<String, Application> event) {
        publisher.publishEvent(new ApplicationCacheExpireEvent(this, event.getOldValue()));
    }
}
```

and

```
@Bean
public List<MapConfig> mapConfigs(final ExpiredListener expiredListener) {
    final MapConfig applicationCache = getMapConfig(APPLICATIONS_CACHE_NAME)
        .setMaxSizeConfig(new MaxSizeConfig()
            .setMaxSizePolicy(MaxSizeConfig.MaxSizePolicy.USED_HEAP_SIZE)
            .setSize(properties.getMaxMapHeapSize()))
            .setTimeToLiveSeconds(properties.getTtlBeforeSave())
            .addEntryListenerConfig(new EntryListenerConfig(expiredListener, false, true));

    final MapConfig warmingCacheMapConfig = getMapConfig(LOCK_MAP_NAME);
    return List.of(applicationCache, warmingCacheMapConfig);
}
```

UPDATE

Hazelcast service is run in docker container

UPDATE 2

1. I used `setTtl` to my imap, but that ruined my server (rest api not supported, but lib version and hazel version are the same)
2. I used `put(K, V, TTL, UNITS)`, aaaand... it does not help!
3. I put `<time-to-live-soconds>` in server `xml` config file, restarted it, and the hazel started to send events!
4. But, then I removed that lines from the `xml` config, reloaded server and it remains working... (I don't use map backup right now)

So, tomorrow I will recheck everything. It seems like either hazelcast docker hangs or `put(K, V, TTL, UNITS)` works.

UPDATE 3 (Solution)

This exact combination works for me

1. Setup TTL in config bean (see code above)
2. Use `put(K, V, ttl, TimeUnits)` instead of `put(K, V)`
3. Explicitly add event listener to hazelcast map

```
    ...
    applications = hazelcastInstance.getMap(APPLICATIONS_CACHE_NAME);
    applications.addEntryListener(new ExpiredListener(this.applicationEventPublisher), true);
    ...
```

Tested both with and without hazelcast server restart.

Comment: If you use `System.out.println()` in your `entryEvicted()` and `entryExpired()` methods does anything appear ? It might be the publisher field isn't being set or serialized correctly on multiple nodes.

Comment: @NeilStevenson I have had problems with de/serialization and fixed them. Ok, I'll try to add logs there, hope that will help.

Comment: @NeilStevenson no, neither entryEvicted nor entryExpired were fired

Comment: Ok, the next easiest thing to check is `map.size()` to see if it reduces -- shows eviction is happening.  If it does reduce, then perhaps it's the serialization of the `Application` object as the entry value -- try it with `<String, String>` to simplify

Comment: @NeilStevenson I spent all day on that((( It started to work, see update 2.

Comment: Does it do this with the latest version (currently 5.1.4) ? If so, and you can reduce it down to a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) confirming it's a bug rather than something else (eg. serialization of `Application`) then it can be fixed.

Comment: @NeilStevenson unfortunately, I use legacy hazelcast and can not upgrade higher 3.12. I have tested all different variants of code and server settings and found working solution (update 3)